# Structured Data with Lazy-Loaded images?

Tags: javascript, css, lazy-loading, structured-data

I want to put in Structured Data tags on Product-Images for SEO reasons.

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="placeholder URL" data-src="Actual URL"/>
```

The problem I'm running into is: Google picks up my SRC value which is only a placeholder image - the actual image(data-src) is only loaded when the user scrolls enough to bring the image into view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `<noscript>` block and put your image with the structured data tag in there. Google will then use that image rather than the image placeholder. This also means any users without JS enabled (there are a few, but they're still about!) will also still see the images. Note: You need to then disable the placeholder images if JS isn't enabled otherwise non-JS users will see two images.

For example

```
 <img class="img-responsive js-only" src="placeholder URL" data-src="Actual URL"/>
 <noscript>
 <img src="Actual URL" data-src="Actual URL" itemprop="image"/>
 </noscript>
```

Verified this approach using Google's structured data testing tool - https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/.

Edit: how to show images only with JS:

You don't need to hide noscript images - anything inside a noscript block is only used if JavaScript is disabled. You can show the responsive images only when JS is enabled by adding class="no-js" to the HTML element, the following JavaScript block to the HEAD:

```
<script>
    var headElement = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]; 
    var regExp = new RegExp('(\\s|^)no-js(\\s|$)'); 
    headElement.className = headElement.className.replace(regExp,' js ');  
</script>
```

and the following CSS:

```
html.no-js .js-only {
    display:none;
}
html.js .no-js {
    display:none
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy! I'm wondering if users still see images "jitter" if I hide <noscript> ones on page-load

Comment: I've added a response to the answer since code formatting doesn't work in comments.

Comment: Nice, neat and slim solution!

Comment: Great idea, although now in 2019, Google appears to be seeing the URL on lazy loaded images.  I can verify in the Search Console ("Crawled Page" in URL Inspection) that it's executed my JavaScript to update the image with the real SRC and even a `lazy-image-loaded` CSS class has been added which my JS adds after loading the image.  The structured data testing tool is also seeing the real lazy loaded image source.  Still would like to implement your `<noscript>` image idea as a general backup, and for other search engines that do not execute JS, and to accommodate those few with JS disabled.

Answer (score 5):

Just add the attribute **content** to your **img** tag with the real image url. Google will use this, but the browser will ignore it.

```
<img src="placeholder URL" data-src="Actual URL" itemprop="image" content="Actual URL" />
```

This is  in my opinion better because you won't need extra **meta**, **noscript** or **JS** code, just one single attribute.

Tested and tried with Google's structured testing tool (https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)

Comment: And what about srcset? Or always link the largest version of the image?

Comment: I'm not sure if Google uses srcset for structured data or SEO. I personally  wouldn't worry about srcset, but the largest image would probably be the most valuable to Google, like you said.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple add just this:

Good typo

```
<meta  itemprop="image" content="your_image_url" />
```

Note the final "/"

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution is to use meta content tags, since they don't render anything like so:

```
<meta content="/img-1.jpg" itemprop="image">
<meta content="/img-2.jpg" itemprop="image">
<meta content="/img-3.jpg" itemprop="image">
```